# PostgreSQL-simple `execute` on a function fails with "execute resulted in Col 1-column result"

Tags: postgresql, haskell, postgresql-simple

I want to execute a Postgres function from Haskell which updates 3 rows but is declared with `RETURNS VOID`. I run the function as follows:

```
catch (do execute conn "select record(?,?)" [id1, id2])
      (\(e :: SomeException) -> do putStrLn ("Exception:" ++ (show e)); return False)
```

but this results in:

```
QueryError {qeMessage = "execute resulted in Col 1-column result", qeQuery = "select record(?,?)"}
```

The query doesn't return results:

```
ebdb=> select record('','');
 record
--------------------

(1 row)
```

How can I execute this Postgresql function from Haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using `query` instead of `execute`:

```
query conn "select 1 from record(?,?)" [id1, id2]
```

`execute` is for statements like `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc. Even though your statement does not return any rows, it is still a `SELECT` so I think you need to use `query` to run it.

Answer (score 1):

This tricky query returns no rows, still the function is executed:

```
select 1 where record('', '') isnull;
```

Comment: Same error. I've gone with converting to a query for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and found this question but wasn't able to switch to `query` because I'm using a library that uses `execute` for database migrations. (I needed an empty/no-op migration.)

Here's what I ended up using which worked:

```
UPDATE arbitrary_but_real_table_name
  SET arbitrary_text_column = 'this will not happen' 
  WHERE 'this is not null' IS NULL;
```

Hope this helps someone!